# How to add wide string prefix to C-style string (in C++)?

Tags: c++, string, c-strings, widestring

How do I add the wide string prefix to a C-style string (in C++)?

I've seen the `L` added to literals:

`L"Hello";`

But given:

`const char cs[] = "Hello";`

neither `L(cs);` nor `(L)cs;` works. What is the correct way to express it?

Comment: 'L' is a literal which instructs the (MSVC's) compiler about how to handle the string constant. It is not a somehow magical operator that can work on variables in run-time (there exist explicit conversion functions designed to perform this task, as referenced in linked question).